# T-SQL Inserting copy of rows from one table to another only with values from variables instead of one column

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datatable, rows

I have seen things like

```
INSERT INTO TableNew
    SELECT *  
    FROM TableOld
    WHERE [Conditions]
```

to copy data/rows form one table to another. But for me.. say TableOld has columns

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
```

and I want to copy only columns

```
C D E F G H I J K L M N
```

of TableOld into TableNew. Both tables have the same number of columns, but the first two of TableNew are Id values that I need to generate for it right before the insert. So I need to insert a new row into TableNew where the first two column's data come from variables, and the rest a copy of some of the columns from a row in TableOld, for each row in TableOld where there is not already a row in TableNew where say TableNew.C = TableOld.c and TableNew.D = TableOld.D.

I thought of doing a cursor to just go through each row of TableOld and do each insert and check for already existing matching (C & D) row, but want to know if there if a better way to do this more like the above.

Comment: What kind of "Id" values do you need to generate? An `identity` column will take care of itself, just omit it from the column lists. Perhaps a GUID with a `default` of [`NewId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? Same deal. Otherwise, specify column lists on both sides, i.e. `insert into TargetTable ( Foo, Bar, Elvis, ... ) select Elvis, ... from SourceTable where ...;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally accepted **best practice** to always explicitly specify the list of columns - both on your `INSERT` statement, as well as using an explicit list of columns on your `SELECT`, rather than `*`:

```
INSERT INTO TableNew (C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N)
    SELECT C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N
    FROM TableOld
    WHERE [Conditions]
```

No messy RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) cursor needed **at all!**

Comment: Yea but how would I include the values for TableNew's A and B columns that are new and need to be made before the insert. That's my main issue I was trying to find a better solution for.

Comment: What do you mean by *need to be made before the insert* ?? Not clear at all ..... But you *can* of course add columns A and B  to the list of columns in the `INSERT` column list, and then provide fixed values as SQL variables in your `SELECT` statement for those two columns...